# Hadoop uses 2 mapper for a small file

Tags: hadoop

I tried to run a map reduce job on a small file (200kb), with only 10 lines. I used hadoop streaming as the map reduce job is written using shell script. I assumed it will use only 1 map, but the job tracker shows 'Map Total' as 2.
Please advice what could be the reason as I assumed the number of mappers will depend on the input file size and the allocated block size.

Thanks

Comment: What is your block size and how many part files(part-m-0000*) files you got in the output directory?

Comment: And was there any mapred.max.split.size set?

Comment: I got just 1 part file in the output directory. I did not set any mapred.max.split.size Vignesh

Comment: One part file implies only one mapper has run. If it had 2 mappers then atleast the second part file would have been zero byte.

Comment: Only 1 output file in output directory, but the tracker mentions as 2 is misleading. Does it occur in Hadoop 1x gen usually?

Comment: I do use hadoop 1x but never seen that. Probably not sure though.